# FB ios SDK - 3.0+ - How can I add permission to [FBSession.activeSession openWithBehaviour: completionHandler]?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

since I don't want the fallback flow starts with iOS6 login dialog, I used

```
[FBSession.activeSession openWithBehaviour: completionHandler]
```

but wonder where I can add the permission parameters, just like `@"basic_info"` and `@"user_like"` in the following method-

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"user_like"]
                               allowLoginUI:YES
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                              FBSessionState status,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              // Respond to session state changes, 
                              // ex: updating the view
                          }];
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's code for -

1. **read permissions**

   ```
   ...
   [FBSession.activeSession requestNewReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"user_likes"]
                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                NSError *error) 
   {
       // Handle new permissions callback
   }];
   ...
   ```
2. **publish permisisions**

   ```
   ...
   [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"publish_actions"]
                                 defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                               completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                   NSError *error) 
   {
      // Handle new permissions callback
   }];
   ...
   ```

Comment: That means I create a active session first using [FBSession.activeSession openWithBehavior:...];And use [FbSession.activeSession requestNewReadPermission ...] to set the permission after a session is successfully created?